# Unexpected boolean result using .nil? on a hash

Tags: ruby, boolean, null

I am working through exercises on codecademy and I came across a solution that I do not completely understand involving .nil? Here is my code :

```
movies = { GIS: 10.0, Phantasm: 1.5, Bourne: 4.0}
puts "Whats your movie brah?"
title = gets.chomp
puts "What's your rating brah?"
rating = gets.chomp
movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
puts "Your info was saved brah!"
case movies
when 'add'
  puts "What movie do you want to add son?"
  title = gets.chomp
  if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
    puts "What's your new rating brah?"
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    puts "#{title} has been added with a rating of #{rating}."
  else
    puts "That movie already exists! Its rating is #{movies[title.to_sym]}."
  end
when "update"
 if movies[title.to_sym].nil?

when "display"
puts "Movies!"
when "delete"
puts "Deleted!"
else puts "Error!"
end
```

I am only referring to the add method. the rest of the script is a work in progress. I don't like not understanding things though and this has me in a bit of a quandry.

My question is does Ruby know not to add a title that already exists because two symbols cannot have the same name? I am curious how it determines when the hash has no value. Can anyone clarify this for me? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: ["Two objects refer to the same hash key when their hash value is identical and the two objects are eql? to each other."](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a bit more complicated than that.

From the [RubyDoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html): "Two objects refer to the same hash key when their `hash` value is identical and the two objects are `eql?` to each other."

An object's `hash` value is a calculated numerical result based on the data the object contains. And the `eql?` method tests if two objects are equal, and this is usually aliased to `==` in ruby (i.e my_string1 == my_string2 is the same as my_string1.eql? my_string2).

When you say `movies[title.to_sym]`, Ruby is saying "In the movies hash, are there any pairs currently stored where the `key.eql? title.to_sym and key.hash == title.to_sym.hash`? If so, return that value of the pairing, and if not return `nil`.

The reason Ruby doesn't add the title if it already exists is because of your `if movies[title.to_sym].nil?` line, which in English translates to "only do what follows if no pairing for the key `title.to_sym` exists."

If you had `title = "GIS"`, and you were to just say `movies[title.to_sym] = 1`, Ruby would gladly over write the `10.0` you currently have stored there so that `movies[:GIS]` returned `1`.